# Scenario to automate the promotion of a read replica when the master db is not responding

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, failover

I would like to set a scenario like the following:

1. Set an RDS event subscription [that the MySQL is unresponsive]
2. that will publish to an SNS topic
3. that will trigger a Lambda function
4. which will run a script that will promote a read replica [in another region] to master

Is such a case feasible?

Which DB metric should I monitor to confirm that the DB is not responding and that there is no false alarm?

Would it be dangerous to automate the promotion of the read replica? Should such actions remain manual and just add alerts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware of **Split Brain**.

The tough problem in promoting a Slave to be Master happens when the problem is in the network.  With a dead network, most types of monitoring will mistakenly think that the Master is dead and promote the Slave.  Now you would have both servers alive and thinking they are the 'Master'.  This condition is called the dreaded "split brain".  Pretty quickly, clients insert duplicate keys and/or generate duplicate auto_increment ids.  The data corruption can be terrible to unravel.

MHA half solves it by promoting a slave when it is sure that it is safe.  If the problem *might* be a network glitch, it punts.

Galera fully solves it by requiring a quorum of nodes to vote that they have the majority.  This, however, requires 3 nodes, preferably in 3 geographic locations.  (Think flood, hurricane, earthquake, etc.)  All nodes can be writable (that's another feature of Galera).  Galera is built into MariaDB and PXC.

Comment: Thanks . That is exactly what I am afraid of and want to be bulletproof [as much as possible..] against. I want the alert/healthcheck not be triggered falsely. I think I'd prefer this operation to be done eventually manually after Cloudwatch has alerted me and a bunch of other admins with SMS/emails .
Both solutions that you propose are in the context of a MySQL DB fully managed by me in an EC2 instance, correct? Cause RDS does not support multi-master architecture and replication.

Comment: There are many cloud services; perhaps some allow Galera-based solutions.